# Блок по верх остальных

Tags: css

Имеется сайт, необходимо поменять расположение блока *новости* из левого нижнего угла в правый верхний?

Научился двигать блок вправо, влево, вверх, вниз, но при передвижении он залезает под остальные блоки. Нашел параметр `z-index`, но с ним все то же самое, где-то ошибаюсь.

```
.art-block {
    position:relative!important; 
    width: 1000px; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: -500px; 
    z-index: 9999; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Этот блок должен располагаться внутри того же блока, что и те, под которые он залазит. Если нет, то `z-index` нужно задавать у родителя и не забыть про позиционирование.

Comment: А не легче кусок кода написать в блоке который с право?